# Getting values of inputs generated using jQuerys html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a page with a table and when I click edit I change the table  elements into inputs using jQuerys html() function.

I then want to have the user edit the values of the inputs and save these to database, problem is when I try and grab the data I get undefined for all the inputs that are created with the html() function.

I am sure it is something to do with this.. Any help would be great! Here is my code:

```
$('[name="edit"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'invoice_number': $(this).attr('data-invoice-number'),
        'count': $(this).attr('data-count')
    };

    var description_text = $('[data-description-' + data.count).text();
    var rates_text = $('[data-rates-' + data.count).text();
    var quantity_text = $('[data-quantity-' + data.count).text();

    console.log(description_text);

    $('[data-description-' + data.count + ']').html('<input type="text" name="description" value="' + description_text + '" />');
    $('[data-rates-' + data.count + ']').html('<input type="text" name="rates" value="' + rates_text + '" />');
    $('[data-quantity-' + data.count + ']').html('<input type="text" name="quantity" value="' + quantity_text + '" />');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $('[name="save"][data-count=' + data.count + ']').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('[name="cancel"][data-count=' + data.count + ']').css('display', 'inline-block');

});
$('[name="save"]').unbind().bind().click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'invoice_number': $('[name="save"]').attr('data-invoice-number'),
        'description': $('[name="description"]').val(),
        'rates': $('[name="rates"]').val(),
        'quantity': $('[name="quantity"]').val(),
    };

    console.log(data); // this outputs undefined for values above generated using html() method

    if (data.description == '') {
        append_alert('danger', 'Please enter a <b>Description</b>');
    } else if (data.rates == '') {
        append_alert('danger', 'Please enter your <b>Rates</b>');
    } else if (data.quantity == '') {
        append_alert('danger', 'Please enter a <b>Quantity</b>');
    } else {
        $.post('edit_invoice_item', data, function() {}).done(function() {
            append_alert('success', 'Item Edited!');
            setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload();
            }, 2000)
        });
    }
});
```

Regards

Comment: can you show your code on jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mudhya8o/ Here is a fiddle, doesn't change to the inputs when edit is clicked however... Not too sure why

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements use `event delegation`

Change

```
$('[name="edit"]').click(function(e) {
```

To

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="edit"]', function(e) {
```

AND

```
$('[name="save"]').unbind().bind().click(function(e) {
```

To

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="save"]', function(e) {
```

Comment: I still get nothing in the console.log(data)